# Unpivot columns to generate rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, unpivot

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT '35111212', '11245452', '42215512'...... and more values.
```

This results in:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
--------           --------            --------
35111212           11245452            42215512
```

And I need to transform it to:

```
(No column name)
--------
35111212
11245452
42215512
```

Is that possible without using a "union"? I have a large amount of values in the select.

Comment: Where are the values from, they are just string values?  Are they from a table? Can you post the table structure?

Comment: Just strings, a lot of! this is the problem cause I cant use union

Comment: But where do you get this list of string from?

Comment: I get the list from a XML file that I have to process in a Delphi app, so in delphi I build a commandText like this. I Cant explain all here sry, but the idea is join a table with this list without using "WHERE IN" and "UNION" cause the list its too big

Comment: You could bring the entire XML blob into a temp table, then use xquery/xpath to pull the values you need out.  Otherwise, if they really are just a bunch of string values, there are not a lot of options in TSQL.

Comment: Yes, I Know, but I need to do it in only one query thats the problem. I was looking for a solution with PIVOT/UNPIVOT if its possible!

Comment: In your delphi code when you build a dynamic query (I guess it is done in a loop of some kind) store the same values in an array AT THE TIME of building the above string. Then use the former for the select statement, and the latter for the IN clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, if your columns are named:

```
select val from  
( 
   select col1 = '1', col2 = '2', col3 = '3'
) a
unpivot 
(
   var for col in (col1, col2, col3)
) as unpvt
```